# Share sass styles across react projects

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

We have multiple front end projects in my company that uses many third party libraries. We override some Css for these libraries locally in each front end project. Is there any way to have such shared styles at one place and refer them in each project instead of duplicating them?

I think we can use npm packages for this but for my company it's not feasible to do so due to financial and time constraints. Are there any other ways to share such common CSS code across multiple projects?

Comment: You can put all of your `CSS` in one folder and use it in all your projects or you can put your CSS in `index.css` and can use it in all your projects.

Comment: You can use git project as a dependency. [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#git-urls-as-dependencies). I believe this is also working even private repository. Another way works effectively if you are the only one front-end developer with multiple projects. Use `yarn link` or `npm link` in your css project.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Different projects are in different GitHub repos. If we keep all the css in one folder. Do we need to refer to that folder in different projects as a URL . Ex: https://www.common-css/shared.css ?

Comment: Thanks Mocha. I was able to share styles using git submodules.